# Isotope.js images not responsive or not filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-isotope

I'm using `jquery.isotope.js` in a Bootstrap page for the image gallery filtering.

It perfectly works in Chrome both filtering and responsive images. But in IE9 and Firefox, when the window size is more than 700px, it works perfectly. Although, when the window size is less than 700px, images will not be responsive.

I've tried editing masonry layout using gutter width, then images became responsive but filtering didn't work. I've tried latest isotope also, but nothing.

Here's the code

```
<!Doctype html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.isotope.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="categories">
            <ul class="cat">
                <li class="pull-left">
                     <h4>PHOTOS</h4> 
                </li>
                <li class="pull-right">
                    <ol class="type">
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="active"> ALL</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".childhood">CHILDHOOD</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".concerts">CONCERTS</a>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="lightbox" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 childhood">
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <img src="img/photos/childhood/img5.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Childhood Images" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 childhood">
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <img src="img/photos/childhood/img2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Childhood Images" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 childhood">
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <img src="img/photos/childhood/img3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Childhood Images" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 concerts">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <img src="img/photos/concerts/img1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Concert Images" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 concerts">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <img src="img/photos/concerts/img1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Concert Images">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(window).load(function() {
                    var $container = $('#lightbox');
                    $container.isotope({
                        filter: '*',
                        animationOptions: {
                            duration: 750,
                            easing: 'linear',
                            queue: false
                        }
                    });
                    $('.cat a').click(function() {
                        $('.cat .active').removeClass('active');
                        $(this).addClass('active');
                        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
                        $container.isotope({
                            filter: selector,
                            animationOptions: {
                                duration: 750,
                                easing: 'linear',
                                queue: false
                            }
                        });
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to use col-xs-4 it is for Extra small devices Phones (<768px)

Comment: When trying to format your HTML code, it seems that you're forgetting to close two `div` tags. Not sure if that's a real problem (talking about the responsiveness), but for sure, it would help if you fix your HTML code.

Comment: but it works well in chrome.Also when I inspect element  the width  seems to be computed in jquery.Really feeling terrible.From 10 days trying hard,not able to resolve it.

Comment: Well I had also problem with IE, cause it allows to get resized even more that other browsers. In real life.. who is resizing it under 700?

Comment: Maybe Chrome auto-closes your `div` tags, and the other browsers don't. Have you tried to close those `div`? You should give a try.

Comment: Ya. just now I did it,not working.When I open in ff or ie when window size is more than 760px it works perfectly.both responsiveness and filtering.when comes down I can see width changes to 800px.

Comment: We should be able to see the webpage in mobile and ipad also no?there comes the problem..

Comment: @user3106135 If you can, post your entire page into a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/), so we can test your page better. Since we don't have yoru CSS codes, nor your images, it's difficult to test responsive design.

Comment: ok.I will do it now.

Comment: @user3106135 mark me in a comment when you have done, please

Comment: sir,I have done it.but didn't get how to include images.also don't know how u can get my code like should I give it a name to the plunker like filename??

Comment: I have entered the code into plunker. Can anybody Pl see to it and help me out..